# Matplotlib stacked bar not showing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to use matplotlib to plot a stacked bar using the following code in python 3.7/3.9:

```
comp1Cost = []
comp2Cost = []
pipeCost = []
installCost = []
secondBottom = []
thirdBottom = []
labelX = []
cnt = 0
for key in aCosts:
    labelX.append(float(aCosts[key]["pipeDetails"]["PressUp"]))
    comp1Cost.append((aCosts[key]["preCompressorCosts"]["CAPEX"]/1000000))
    pipeCost.append((aCosts[key]["pipeCosts"]["totalCost"]/1000000))
    installCost.append((aCosts[key]["pInstallCost"]["total_install_cost"]/1000000))
    comp2Cost.append((aCosts[key]["poCompressorCosts"]["CAPEX"]/1000000))
    secondBottom.append((comp1Cost[cnt]+pipeCost[cnt]))
    thirdBottom.append((comp1Cost[cnt]+pipeCost[cnt]+installCost[cnt]))
    cnt = 1 + cnt
fig,bx = plt.subplots()

bx.bar(labelX, pipeCost,1,label="Pipe Material Cost",color='r')
bx.bar(labelX, comp1Cost, 1, bottom=pipeCost,label="Pre Compressor Costs", color='b')
bx.bar(labelX, installCost,1,label="Pipe Install Cost",color='g',bottom=secondBottom)
bx.bar(labelX, comp2Cost,1,label="Post Compressor Costs",color='y',bottom=thirdBottom)

print("labelX",labelX)
print("pipeCost",pipeCost)
print("comp1Cost",comp1Cost)
print("comp2Cost",comp2Cost)
print("installCost",installCost)

bx.set_ylabel("Cost million")
bx.set_xlabel("Pipeline inlet pressure - Pascals")
bx.set_title("CAPEX Cost Breakdown")
bx.legend()
plt.savefig('bar.png')
plt.show()
```

Once loaded, the arrays are as below. The axes shows and has the correct scaling and labels (when those aren't commented out). But the actual graph is blank and there are no bars.

I can't quite find the error and would welcome any suggestions.

labelX [3000000.0, 3700000.0, 4400000.0, 5100000.0, 5800000.0, 6500000.0, 7200000.0, 7900000.0, 8600000.0, 9300000.0]
pipeCost [39.205836829440045, 49.29444816201567, 56.084000633780626, 66.36404671650006, 73.28122235502757, 83.75270318789067, 90.79750199318073, 101.4604175761876, 108.63283954824009, 119.48718988139075]
comp1Cost [0.0, 0.8344540759301868, 1.3909883215855556, 1.829099552307249, 2.1775934319847634, 2.497231609417327, 2.772435378973363, 3.0001466918008792, 3.2102150554113407, 3.426855354135507]
comp2Cost [2.7045137658080356, 2.120792548365006, 1.6448839113097127, 1.1847748864728636, 0.7676367792465681, 0.3605770879284079, 2.772435378973363, 3.0001466918008792, 3.2102150554113407, 3.426855354135507]
installCost [24.454735004448, 24.455953435768357, 24.456773430028235, 24.4580149814875, 24.458850389173314, 24.460115060771486, 24.460965881883233, 24.462253673620314, 24.463119908158, 24.464430820033986]

Thanks,
Scott C

Comment: ``bx.bar(labelX, pipeCost)`` is not supposed to be written like that.

Answer (score 1):

in bar plot, the x axis is 1,2,3 and so on. Your `labelX` should be just a ticklabel, not X value

```
labelX = [3000000.0, 3700000.0, 4400000.0, 5100000.0, 5800000.0, 6500000.0, 7200000.0, 7900000.0, 8600000.0, 9300000.0]
pipeCost = [39.205836829440045, 49.29444816201567, 56.084000633780626, 66.36404671650006, 73.28122235502757, 83.75270318789067, 90.79750199318073, 101.4604175761876, 108.63283954824009, 119.48718988139075]
comp1Cost = [0.0, 0.8344540759301868, 1.3909883215855556, 1.829099552307249, 2.1775934319847634, 2.497231609417327, 2.772435378973363, 3.0001466918008792, 3.2102150554113407, 3.426855354135507]
comp2Cost = [2.7045137658080356, 2.120792548365006, 1.6448839113097127, 1.1847748864728636, 0.7676367792465681, 0.3605770879284079, 2.772435378973363, 3.0001466918008792, 3.2102150554113407, 3.426855354135507]
installCost =  [24.454735004448, 24.455953435768357, 24.456773430028235, 24.4580149814875, 24.458850389173314, 24.460115060771486, 24.460965881883233, 24.462253673620314, 24.463119908158, 24.464430820033986]

fig,bx = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(10)

bx.bar(x, pipeCost,1,label="Pipe Material Cost",color='r')
bx.bar(x, comp1Cost, 1, bottom=pipeCost,label="Pre Compressor Costs", color='b')
bx.bar(x, installCost,1,label="Pipe Install Cost",color='g')
bx.bar(x, comp2Cost,1,label="Post Compressor Costs",color='y')
bx.set_xticks(x)
bx.set_xticklabels(labelX, rotation=20, fontsize=7)

bx.set_ylabel("Cost million")
bx.set_xlabel("Pipeline inlet pressure - Pascals")
bx.set_title("CAPEX Cost Breakdown")
bx.legend()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: This worked a treat. Thanks so much. I'd wasted a morning trying to work this out!

Comment: Then please do mark my answer as "accepted" ;)